# IBM DB2 Backup and Restore

Tags: db2

I have two different databases in db2. Can I merge two separate backups taken at different times. If so, please explain the method for doing so.

Comment: How can we help you if your question is so broad?

Comment: It would definitely help if you were more specific on what you want to do. e.g. What fields would you like to merge. What rules do you want in place two specify which backup should take precedence etc. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can not merge 2 backup images, the workaround is to export 2 databases' tables out etc. and import them into one database.